# How to visualize two-class linear discriminant analysis with multiple attributes

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization

For a two-class linear discriminant analysis problem.

If each class has only two properties, I can easily use these two properties as the x-axis and y-axis of the Cartesian coordinate system, using a point to represent an instance in the coordinate system. [image: just like it]

Similarly, if a class has three properties, I can represent it in a space Cartesian coordinate system.

my question is: If the class has four or more properties, how should I handle it so that it can be visualized

Comment: You could perform LDA on the principal components of the attributes and then plot the discriminant and the data projected on the first two PCs.